# JPA transactions and triggers/scheduled jobs possible conflicts

Tags: java, jpa, plsql, triggers, jobs

In our application we use **PL/SQL** to maintain the persistence of data, we also heavily use **PL/SQL** stored procedures, scheduled jobs and triggers to implement parts of the application logic.

*My question is:*

Using **JPA** to access this persistence should I worry about conflicts
that **JPA transactions** can potentially have with the aforementioned triggers and scheduled jobs defined on the **DB** ?

It would be very helpfulf also if you can point to some online materials
that I can read to clear my doubts.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may defiantly have problem. Having business logic implemented in the DB might potentially lead to code duplication. But you biggest problem is related to the data integrity and consistency:

1. Is you application using optimistic locking. If yes, then it is possible that the JPA will not be able to see the changes in the versions of the respected entities. And will not throw optimistic lock exception if a change happens due to PLSQl code. Unless the versioning is implemented in it as well.
2. Caching.  If you use caching you might end up in a situation where your cache is not consistent with the database State. For example you read entity A the state is cached then PLSQL background procedure updates its state. Then you make another update and persist and Ta data... you have problem. And then again, we go to point one with how the data is versioned.

In general, mixing PL/SQL and Hibernate I really dislike it...